# What is this English tree with oval leaves and pale pink blossoms?

Tags: identification, trees

Does anyone know what type of tree this is?

[image: tree in bloom]

Located in Leicestershire, UK.

Answer (score 2):

This will start the IDs!  I vote for *Prunus laurocerasus*. [English Laurel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_laurocerasus)

Answer (score 1):

It's not common laurel, *Prunus laurocerasus*. Take a look at *Prunus lusitanica*, common name Portugal laurel. The leaves and red stems look like a good match. The flowers should be white, but if they're going over they might look like those in the photo.